# How To Enable Upload In IIS

Tags: http, iis, cordova

I have a folder on my IIS instance called Uploads. I am doing an HTTP POST from my Android application to upload a file to the IIS server.

This isn't working. The operation looks like this (this is part of the failed request logging),

```
<failedRequest url="http://*ADDRESS*:80/JsonWCFService/Uploads"
           siteId="1"
           appPoolId=".NET4 App Pool"
           processId="1176"
           verb="POST"
           remoteUserName=""
           userName=""
           tokenUserName="NT AUTHORITY\IUSR"
           authenticationType="anonymous"
           activityId="{00000000-0000-0000-6800-0080000000FA}"
           failureReason="STATUS_CODE"
           statusCode="200"
           triggerStatusCode="405"
           timeTaken="63"
           xmlns:freb="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2006/06/iis/freb"
           >
```

So we are getting a 405 there. Do I need to configure something more in IIS?

I am using the PhoneGap API to upload the file using the FileTransfer.upload method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IIS` is a `web server` and it does not come with a build-in `upload handler`. If you would like to upload files using `POST` on a specific `url` you would have to create an actual web-application.

*Read more here:* http://support.microsoft.com/kb/189651

The simplest solution that I can propose is to create a new `asp.net` project with a `HttpHandler` - the code could look something like this (*as simple as it can be*):

```
public class UploadHandler : IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState
{        
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpPostedFile file = context.Request.Files[0];
            file.SaveAs(path);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // include your custom logging code
            // Log.Error(ex.Message, ex);
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Please keep in mind that this is acceptable for *small* files, you should **not** use it for something heavier than couple of *MB*.

Comment: Are you sure? I don't want to create an HttpHandler. I just want the files to be uploaded directly to a folder. Regardless I might give it a go.

Comment: So what would you use for files over a couple of MB?

Comment: I've added a link for more details on the `IIS` file upload functionality. For large files I would go with a WCF / Web Service and for extremely large files (~1GB) I would only go with FTP.

Comment: A custom handler for the minute looks good. This is just a demo / proof of concept. The fact it works is the main thing.

Comment: @MonkeyCoder Hi, I am getting an `array out of bounds` error. I tried your code too but still got the same error. I suspect that the file is not getting posted correctly. Can you please have a look at [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14620007/saving-a-file-posted-using-http-post).

Comment: Hey, do you have any idea if this is still true? I'm trying to use IIS as a server, and it's hard for me to believe IIS still doesn't have an upload handler/server built-in. (7 years later..)