# WebClient.UploadFile is not working

Tags: c#, http, web, webclient

I want to upload a normal .txt file to my own webserver. The webserver runs local on my machine. Its a apache webserver.

For this task I use the WebClient Method "UploadFile()".

But this is not working and i dont know why.

On my webserver I have a directory "documents". This directory is open for reading and writing.

Let's see my code:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string url= "";
try
{
    url= "http://localhost/documents/";

    client.UploadFile(url, filename);                       

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error:\n" + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
}
```

"fileName" is usually a random .txt file from my desktop.

I don't get any exception or error. Everything looks fine ..

But there is no file in my "documents" folder. Why? What should I do?

Comment: this MSDN page might help you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.uploadfile.aspx

Comment: Can you post your server side code? That might help.

Answer (score 0):

> On my webserver I have a directory "documents". This directory is open for reading and writing.

the documents in `http://localhost/documents/` is your controller's name. WebClient will send a `POST` request to this `URL`. Then in the controller's POST action method you should handle the uploading part.

Hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9006157/275501 which I believe is similar to the question you have asked.